# How do We Search A Records In Datatables On Input Focus?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I  Am Passing Value In Search Box  Using Jquery  But it's not working for search I Have to move my cursor Then it's working (maybe search box default event is keyup ) so how do I make work when it gets focused.

```
$('#ga-search').val(startdate);
$('#employee-grid_filter input[type=search]').focus();
```

Comment: is it `onChange()` Check it first. If yes than change it to `onKeyup()`

Comment: Yep, You are right. Its Working Fine now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have  Replaced Below Code And Its Working Fine

```
$('#ga-search').val(startdate).trigger('keyup');
```

Comment: Thanks You have  Saved My Time

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help